# What is "the song called Peter"?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, taras-shevchenko, the-complete-kobzar

The poem *Maryanne the Nun* by Taras Shevchenko contains the following lines:

> You won't recall that orphan
> Dressed in peasant garb, at times, so happy
> When he saw the wonder - of your beauty,
> Whom you taught
> Not using words
> To use the eyes, the soul and heart to speak,
> With whom you smiled, cried and worried,
> To whom you loved to sing the song called *Peter*.

What is "the song called *Peter*"?

Comment: Where did you get this translation please?

Comment: @DVK It's a Peter Fedynsky translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched for the original Ukrainian title "Мар’яна-черниця" and found the following page:
https://www.t-shevchenko.name/uk/Kobzar/1841/MarjanaChernycja.html 
where there are the poem and notes below. 
And indeed, one of the notes deals with the line "Кому ти любила Петруся співать". It says that it is about the folk song "Була собі Маруся, полюбила Петруся".

It is a funny Ukrainian folk song about a girl Marusya who fancies Petrus: 
http://yavoryna.kiev.ua//Bula_sobi_Marusia.htm

This Shevchenko's poem is dedicated to Oksana Kovalenko, his childhood friend.

Comment: Is there a reference as to why the notes chose that specific song?

Comment: @DVK I'm not Ukrainian, I too must just believe it. However, I can imagine if it were my culture I would know which song is meant.

Answer (score 3):

OK, first of all, here's the original text in Russian:

> Моя черноброва,
> Ты даже не вспомнишь, меня сироту.
> Что в серой сермяге, когда то, счастливый,
> Как диво увидел – твою красоту,
> Тогда ты безмолвно, меня научила,
> Глазами и сердцем, влюбится в мечту.
> Кому улыбалась, рыдала, грустила,
> **Кому же любила ты петь Петруся,**
> Ты даже не вспомнишь, Оксана, Оксана,
> А я только плачу, горит вся душа.
> ...
> **О Петрусе вспомни, улыбнись ты счастливо,**
> *(source: https://www.chitalnya.ru/work/2539123/)*

I can see 2 interpretations:

1. The narrator is talking **to** a woman named Petrusya (Ukrainian version of feminine dimunitive version of name Peter). This is supported by the fact that he also addresses other women in the text, like Oksana in next line. In this case, the correct translation of that line would be *"Petrusya, who did you love to sing to?"*; as well as the use of nominative case ("Именительный падеж") in the name - see discussion of that in detail in the note for the second interpretation.

   Additional argument for this interpretation is 7 lines down, where he says "*О Петрусе вспомни, улыбнись ты счастливо,*" "Remember about Petrusya, and smile happily". This to me seems to indicate that he should remember a PERSON, although in theory one could have phrased that line to have been about a song, but to me that line would have sounded very klunky if it wasn't about a person.

   However, there are 2 arguments against this (name) interpretation:

   - in the next line after yours, the one addressing "Oksana", has a comma before the addressed name, which seems correct if I recall my russian grammar rules well, whereas, there is NO comma before "Petrusya". This may indicate that "Петруся" was indeed NOT an address to a person by that name, but instead as you alluded to the name of the song.
   - Oksana has a logical place in the text as far as being addressed - she is Maryanne's sister based on subsequent lines ("*Так вспомни Оксана, чужая, красива, Сестренку Марьяну, рястом укрывай,*"). Whereas, I can't figure out a logical place for a SECOND addressee from the text.
2. If "Петруся" was indeed the song name, my best guess is it was "Petrusya fell in love" / "Полюбила Петруся" - a folk Ukrainian song. [Here's one on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcK8pC5snMY). Here's [the lyrics](http://lyricshare.net/ru/kubanskiy-kazachiy-hor/polyubila-petrusya.html).

   However, I see a problem with this interpretation as well, since the grammatical case ("Именительный падеж"/"Nominative case") in your line (Петрус**я**) is wrong - if he was talking about a song named "Петруся", the expression "singing song named X" would have instead used the "Петрус**ю**" - note different vowel at the end (which would be "Винительный падеж"/"[Accusative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case)"); since the song name would be a direct object of a transitive verb. Using nominative case as the author did, points to that being the name of the person being addressed.

So, you pick your poison - the comma difference hints at it being a song and the case/падеж difference hints at it being the name of a person being addressed.

Since the poem was never finished, we don't know which of the two would be fixed after editing.

Comment: Also, word of advice - do NOT google that poem on work PC. Original pages where Shevchenko wrote his draft had some... [not quite suitable for workplace doodles](https://www.t-shevchenko.name/ru/Painting/MarjanaChernycja/Page5.html).